# Expression NOT IN or NOT INCLUDE in mapbox

Tags: expression, mapbox

Im currently using mapbox tileset.
Here is my layer config:

{

```
"id": "data-4fwhh8",
"type": "fill",
"source": "data-4fwhh8",
"source-layer": "data-4fwhh8",
"paint": {
  'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(150, 150, 150,0.4)',
  'fill-color': 'rgba(150, 150, 150,0.1)'
},
"filter": ["in", "id", ...keysFiltered]
```

}
// keysFiltered is an array contains list of id

And i want to filter items thats NOT INCLUDE in "keysFiltered".

I don't know how to do it, please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found the solution:

```
{
    "id": "data-4fwhh8",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "data-4fwhh8",
    "source-layer": "data-4fwhh8",
    "paint": {
      'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(150, 150, 150,0.4)',
      'fill-color': 'rgba(150, 150, 150,0.1)'
    },
    "filter": ['match', ['get', 'id'], keysFiltered, false, true]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [logical negation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#!) expression:

```
"filter": ["!",["in", "id", ...keysFiltered]]
```

Comment: Since i've got the error using this expression `mapbox.js:96 Error: layers[122].filter[4][0]: expected one of [==, !=, >, >=, <, <=, in, !in, all, any, none, has, !has, within], "!" found`
i would suggest `["!in", "id", ...keysFiltered]`